# Batch read file name and change content creation date

Tags: photos, mojave

I have a lot of photos/videos named: 2012-04-05 19.21.34.jpg

Somehow, the creation date has been completely changed however.

Is there a way to replace the creation date with the info from the filename?

Comment: Are all photos named in the same form? Are they all in the same directory or spread across several?

Comment: All named in the same form, and in the same directory!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the naming convention is the same for all files in the same directory, then in **Terminal**, `cd` to that `directory` and use the following *compound command*:

```
for f in *.*; do touch -t $(sed -e 's:\.[a-z].*::' -e 's:\.::' -e 's:[- ]::g'<<<"$f") "$f"; done
```

---

Explanation of some of the *compound command*:

- `for f in *.*; do ...; done` - Loop through files.
- `touch -t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]` - Change the access and modification times to the specified time instead of the current time of day.
- `$(...)` - Command substitution, replaces the command(s) with the result, literally.
- `sed` - Stream editor for filtering and transforming text.

  - `−e script` - Add the script to the commands to be executed.
  - `'s:\.[a-z].*::'` - This strips the file extension in e.g.: `2012-04-05 19.21.34.jpg`

    - Returns: `2012-04-05 19.21.34`
  - `'s:\.::'` -  This removes the first `.` in e.g.: `2012-04-05 19.21.34`

    - Returns: `2012-04-05 1921.34`
  - `'s:[- ]::g'` - This removes `-` and the *space* in e.g.: `2012-04-05 1921.34`

    - Returns: `201204051921.34`

Which is the perfect format for the `-t` *option* in the `touch` *command*.

---

Please note that the original *compound command* is formed a bit loose. In other words, it can be written to expressly target `.jpg` files where the extension is lower case as in your example, e.g.: `2012-04-05 19.21.34.jpg`

- Replacing the `*.*` in `for f in *.*; do ...; done` with: `in *.jpg`
- Replacing the `[a-z].*` in `sed -e 's:\.[a-z].*::'` with: `jpg`

```
for f in *.jpg; do touch -t $(sed -e 's:\.jpg::' -e 's:\.::' -e 's:[- ]::g'<<<"$f") "$f"; done
```

Since the `-t` *option* is being used with the `touch` *command*, any *filename* that doesn't produce the expected output, the worst case scenario with it written a bit loose is its not going to impact non-target files and will simply error out on those files with:

```
touch: out of range or illegal time specification: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]
```

So, written a bit loose or more targeted, the end results will be the same and, only files with the naming convention of e.g. `2012-04-05 19.21.34.jpg` will be touched.

---

**NOTE:** Always make sure you have a current backup before wholesale processing files.

Comment: thanks again - my vote is not counted but i did my part

Comment: @EinsteinOTB, If you look at your [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/343471/einsteinotb?tab=reputation), page, you'll see you got as +2 for accepting the answer and a +5 for my upvote of your question. Click the arrow next to... Batch read file name and change content creation date on your reputation page to expand it to see what makes up the +15 on the question so far.

Comment: Let `date` do the formatting- `date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S" "${f%.*}" +"%Y%m%d%H%M.%S"`

Comment: For those wanting to use the suggestion by fd0, replace what's inside of the Command Substitution _command_ `$(...)` with his suggested code. In other words remove the `sed` _command_, replacing it with the `date` _command_ mentioned in the comment by  fd0.